# Select value based on ranges defined in a second table

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ratings](
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] int NOT NULL,
    [UserId] int NOT NULL,
    [Rating] [int] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Ratings] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RatingScales](
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [Rating1] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Rating2] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Rating3] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Rating4] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Rating5] [real] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.RatingScales] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Then I began with:

```
SELECT R.CompanyId, AVG(R.Rating) AS Average
FROM Ratings AS R
GROUP BY R.CompanyId
```

The RatingScales fields (Rating1, ..., Rating5) contains the minimum value for each range:

```
Rating1 >= 1.2
Rating2 >= 2.3
...
Rating5 >= 4.6
```

What I need is to return the corresponding range which the average rating is in.

For instance:

```
CompanyId | Rating  | Average
1         | Rating1 | 1.5
2         | Rating4 | 4
3         | Rating2 | 2.8
4         | NULL    | 0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
--Id from the RatingScales table that you want to use
DECLARE @ratingId INT = 1;

--Common Table Expression to get the Average
WITH avgRating AS 
    (SELECT R.CompanyId, AVG(R.Rating * 1.00) AS Average
    FROM Ratings AS R
    GROUP BY R.CompanyId)

--Determine which rating category the company is in
SELECT CompanyId,
       CASE WHEN Average >= (SELECT Rating1 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) AND 
       Average < (SELECT Rating2 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) THEN 'Rating1'
       WHEN Average >= (SELECT Rating2 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) AND 
       Average < (SELECT Rating3 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) THEN 'Rating2' 
       WHEN Average >= (SELECT Rating3 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) AND 
       Average < (SELECT Rating4 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) THEN 'Rating3'
       WHEN Average >= (SELECT Rating4 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) AND 
       Average < (SELECT Rating5 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) THEN 'Rating4' 
       WHEN Average >= (SELECT Rating4 FROM RatingScales WHERE Id = @ratingId) THEN 'Rating5'   
       ELSE NULL END 'Rating',
       CAST(Average AS decimal(3,2)) 'Average'
FROM avgRating
```